# How to run git-bash commands from Python Fabric on Windows

Tags: python, windows, git, fabric, git-bash

We're using Python 2.7 Fabric 1.13 on Windows 12 Server, on which is also installed Git-Bash for it's almost linux-like terminal. Amazingly, we've gotten it all to work - almost. It's a hodgepodge, but seems less clunky than Cygwin.

I have a script in my user's `~/.bash_profile` which works fine when I run it manually inside of Git-bash CLI. This script is a local preparation for what is to come next.

When I try to use Fabric's `local` command to run this function, it just errors with `return code 1`. I'm assuming that my function, a function in my user's environment, is not present when Fabric is running.

How do I find the user that my fabric script runs as (again, on Windows)? And more to the point, how do I inject this code (function) into that user's environment? Or, how do I make it global to all users?

Comment: I'm getting a similar error, but in my case it seems to be because the paths are Windows paths, so my string formatting causes an issue e.g. `C:\windows\.../oopslinux/`